# Re-recording fingers flex sensors

Tags: python, animation

I have data from flex sensor on ring and pinky fingers and I want to record them into an already animated character, I tried to record through `.keyframe_insert` but it does not record frames for some time, the desynchronization is underway.

```
import bpy
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    from collections import Counter
    global origin

    origin = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].pose.bones

    scn = bpy.context.scene

    scn.frame_current = 0
    scn.frame_start = 0
    scn.frame_end = 615 # get in Iclone 7 WARNING!!!!!
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.auto_keying_mode = 'REPLACE_KEYS'
    bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.use_keyframe_insert_auto = True



    pathTime = r"C:\Program Files\Reallusion\iClone  7\Bin64\OpenPlugin\MotionLIVE\TimeMocap.csv"
    pathValues = r"C:\Users\bakzh\Desktop\CaptoGloveFinal\CaptoGloveFinal\Values.csv"

    def NormalizedSensorValue(Value, min, max):
        rng = max - min
        x = min + (Value * rng) / 1.0

        return np.clip(x, 0.0, max)

    def MAA(Values):

        window_size = 3
        i = 0
        moving_averages = []

        while i < len(Values) - window_size + 1:

            window = Values[i: i + window_size]
            window_average = round(sum(window) / window_size, 2)
            moving_averages.append(window_average)
            i += 1
        return moving_averages

    def find_nearest(array, value):
        array = np.asarray(array)
        idx = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()
        return idx

    def get_quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw):
      qx = np.sin(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2) - np.cos(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2)
      qy = np.cos(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2) + np.sin(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2)
      qz = np.cos(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2) - np.sin(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2)
      qw = np.cos(roll/2) * np.cos(pitch/2) * np.cos(yaw/2) + np.sin(roll/2) * np.sin(pitch/2) * np.sin(yaw/2)
 
      return [qw, qx, qy, qz]



    global Right_4_Angle_180
    global Right_5_Angle_180

    MoCap_Time = pd.read_csv(pathTime, names=["Flags", "Time"])
    Values = pd.read_csv(pathValues, names=["Glove", "IndSensor", "Values", "TimeSensor"])
    start = MoCap_Time["Time"][0]
    stop = MoCap_Time["Time"][1]

    Right_4_Values = []
    Right_5_Values = []

    start = find_nearest(Values["TimeSensor"], start)

    stop = find_nearest(Values["TimeSensor"], stop)

    for j in range(start, stop):
        if Values["IndSensor"][j] == 4:
            Right_4_Values.append(Values["Values"][j])
        if Values["IndSensor"][j] == 5:
            Right_5_Values.append(Values["Values"][j])

    Right_4_Angle_180 = []
    Right_5_Angle_180 = []


    for Value in MAA(Right_4_Values):
        Right_4_Angle_180.append(-NormalizedSensorValue(Value, 0.0, 1.57))
    for Value in MAA(Right_5_Values):
        Right_5_Angle_180.append(-NormalizedSensorValue(Value, 0.0, 1.57))



    class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
        """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
        bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
        bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

        _timer = None


    def move_Hand(self, context, scene):
        global Right_4_Angle_180_Gen1
        global Right_4_Angle_180_Gen2
        global Right_4_Angle_180_Gen3

        global Right_5_Angle_180_Gen1
        global Right_5_Angle_180_Gen2
        global Right_5_Angle_180_Gen3
        global origin
        
        try:
            q = get_quaternion_from_euler(next(Right_4_Angle_180_Gen1), 0, 0)

            origin["CC_Base_L_Ring1"].rotation_quaternion[0], origin["CC_Base_L_Ring1"].rotation_quaternion[3],origin["CC_Base_L_Ring1"].rotation_quaternion[2],origin["CC_Base_L_Ring1"].rotation_quaternion[1] = q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3]
            print(origin["CC_Base_L_Ring1"].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=-1))
            #print(time.localtime().tm_sec)   
            
            #origin["CC_Base_L_Ring2"].rotation_euler[2]  = next(Right_4_Angle_180_Gen2)
            #origin["CC_Base_L_Ring2"].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=-1, options={'INSERTKEY_REPLACE'})

            #origin["CC_Base_L_Ring3"].rotation_euler[2]  = next(Right_4_Angle_180_Gen3)
            #origin["CC_Base_L_Ring3"].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=-1, options={'INSERTKEY_REPLACE'})


            #origin["CC_Base_L_Pinky1"].rotation_euler[2]  = next(Right_5_Angle_180_Gen1)
            #origin["CC_Base_L_Pinky1"].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=-1, options={'INSERTKEY_REPLACE'})


            #origin["CC_Base_L_Pinky2"].rotation_euler[2]  = next(Right_5_Angle_180_Gen2)
            #origin["CC_Base_L_Pinky2"].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=-1, options={'INSERTKEY_REPLACE'})
            
            
            #origin["CC_Base_L_Pinky3"].rotation_euler[2]  = next(Right_5_Angle_180_Gen3)
            #origin["CC_Base_L_Pinky3"].keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=-1, options={'INSERTKEY_REPLACE'})


        except StopIteration:
            bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)
            print("Recorded")

    def execute(self, context):

        global Right_4_Angle_180_Gen1
        global Right_4_Angle_180_Gen2
        global Right_4_Angle_180_Gen3

        global Right_4_Angle_180

        Right_4_Angle_180_Gen1 = (Angle for Angle in Right_4_Angle_180)
        Right_4_Angle_180_Gen2 = (Angle for Angle in Right_4_Angle_180)
        Right_4_Angle_180_Gen3 = (Angle for Angle in Right_4_Angle_180)

        global Right_5_Angle_180_Gen1
        global Right_5_Angle_180_Gen2
        global Right_5_Angle_180_Gen3

        global Right_5_Angle_180

        Right_5_Angle_180_Gen1 = (Angle for Angle in Right_5_Angle_180)
        Right_5_Angle_180_Gen2 = (Angle for Angle in Right_5_Angle_180)
        Right_5_Angle_180_Gen3 = (Angle for Angle in Right_5_Angle_180)

        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(self.move_Hand)

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I'm sorry I did the first post wrong I couldn't delete it